# enlarge image in new window - centered?

Tags: javascript, jquery

enlarging an image in a new window when a user clicks on it. Here's the Javascript I used:

```
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--

function PopUp(pPage) {
window.open(pPage,'popWin','resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=580,height=460,toolbar=no');
}

//-->
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
<A href="javascriptopUp('picture.jpg');"><img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt="" border=0></a>
</body>
</html>
```

This has worked great for me but I need to have the large image in the new window centered. I've tried adding "align=center" to various parts of both the  part of the code as well as the  part of the code. Nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load a HTML document to achieve that. You are loading only a plain images. In this case, you have no influence to its position, because the browser only renders an image.